# Can we build Fresnel lens for neutrinos?

Tags: diffraction, neutrinos, lenses

Suppose we know neutrino mass and speed. This makes us know it's [de Broglie wavelength](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matter_wave) in vacuum. Now suppose it is travelling through matter filled by some "atoms" with concentration $n$ and with scattering cross section of $\sigma$.

Is this information enough to compute refraction coefficient of this medium and, hence, build [Fresnel lense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_lens) for neutrino? Can we build, say, giant lense and focus neutrinos on other side of Earth or on the moon? Are there any calculations of this known?

Comment: Well, first you need a large supply of unobtanium as that's the only material which has a measurable "index of refraction" for neutrinos.

Comment: How do you know? You need to calculate first!

Comment: Your problem will lie in $\sigma$, we know the cross section of neutrinos with matter reasonably well and it's quite...small.

Comment: @Dims  seriously?  You need to look up neutrino cross-sections